# Simple C++98 actor system (with event system) - think Doom or Unreal

Tags: c++, event-handling, actor, c++98

I am finishing up an actor system (like those used in 90s games, like *Doom*, *Unreal*, etc.), which currently deals with damage and event handling.

**actor.cpp**

```
/*
 * Actor System
 * (with Event System included)
 *
 * Author: Gustavo Ramos "Gustavo6046" Rehermann.
 * (c)2018. The MIT License.
 *
 * This system basically allows the creation of
 * Actors (entities), in a game world. This does
 * not handle 3D coordinates nor collision. I
 * have neither ideas nor time to implement those,
 * so I hope someone will implement those on top
 * of this code, either extending it or modifying it.
 *
 * For the sake of extensibility, actors aren't removed
 * when they die. That task is here delegated to the 
 * upper levels.
 *
 * For an example of a possible extension:
 *
 *      struct Vec3
 *      {
 *          int XYZ[3];
 *      }
 *
 *      struct G_PhysicalActor
 *      {
 *          G_Actor* baseActor;
 *          Vec3 pos;
 *          int colCylinderRadius;
 *          int colCylinderHeight;
 *          // ...
 *      }
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "actor.h" // > structs

E_ActorEvent*   E_BaseEvent = NULL;    // > Master actor event linked list.
G_Actor*        G_Actors = NULL;       // > Master actor linked list.
unsigned int    G_NumActors = 0;

// > This function shall append actor events
//   to the master event linked list (I call
//   this event notification).
void G_NotifyActorEvent(E_ActorEvent* evt)
{   
    evt->nextEvent = NULL;

    if ( E_BaseEvent == NULL )
        E_BaseEvent = evt;

    else
    {
        E_ActorEvent* e = NULL;
        for ( e = E_BaseEvent; e->nextEvent != NULL; e = e->nextEvent );    // > quick way to get
                                                                            //   the last event on
                                                                            //   the linked list :)

        e->nextEvent = evt;
    }
}

// > Returns the next actor event.
//   
E_ActorEvent* G_PollActorEvent()
{
    // > For the sake of while loop polling, we want
    //   to return NULL (0) when there is no event.
    if ( !E_BaseEvent ) return NULL;

    // > Since our linked list is like a queue, we want
    //   to take only the 1st event (FIFO), and the 2nd
    //   will become the 1st. Fortunately, this is very
    //   easy to do.
    E_ActorEvent* res = E_BaseEvent;
    E_BaseEvent = res->nextEvent;


    return res;
}

// > Handle actor death (health being
//   smaller than or equal to 0).
void G_Die(G_Actor* actor)
{
    // > At the moment, all it does is notify an event.
    //   This may change.

    E_ActorEvent* evt = new E_ActorEvent;
    evt->eventType = AEV_DEATH;
    evt->actor = actor;
    G_NotifyActorEvent(evt);
}

// > Create an actor and append it to
//   the master Actor linked list.
G_Actor* G_CreateActor(int health)
{
    // > Initializes the actor.
    G_Actor* a = new G_Actor;

    _G_DamageTrack* dmg = new _G_DamageTrack;
    dmg->health = health;
    dmg->totalDamage = 0;
    dmg->totalHeal = 0;
    a->damage = *dmg;
    a->index = G_NumActors;

    char* estr = new char[1]; // allocate an empty string.
    *estr = 0; // strings terminate with a null byte.
    std::fill_n(a->damageFactor_K, 256, estr);
    std::fill_n(a->damageFactor_V, 256, 1000);

    // > Adds the actor to the list.
    if ( G_Actors == NULL )
        G_Actors =  a;

    else
    {
        // > Find last element on actor list, then append
        //   to it.
        G_Actor* prev;
        for ( prev = G_Actors; prev->nextActor != NULL; prev = prev->nextActor );
        prev->nextActor = a;
    }

    // > Notify the actor's creation.
    G_NumActors++;

    E_ActorEvent* evt = new E_ActorEvent;
    evt->eventType = AEV_CREATED;
    evt->actor = a;
    G_NotifyActorEvent(evt);
    a->nextActor = NULL;

    return a;
}

// > Removes this actor from the list, by address.
bool G_RemoveActor(G_Actor* actor)
{
    G_Actor* a = NULL;

    if ( G_Actors == actor )
    {
        G_Actors = NULL;
        return true;
    }

    if ( G_Actors == NULL )
        return false;

    for ( a = G_Actors; a->nextActor != NULL && a->nextActor != actor; a = a->nextActor )

    if ( a == NULL || a->nextActor == NULL )
        return false;

    if ( a->nextActor != NULL )
    {
        a->nextActor = a->nextActor->nextActor;

        if ( a->nextActor != NULL )
            for ( G_Actor* cur = a->nextActor; cur != NULL; cur = cur->nextActor )
                cur->index--;
    }

    else
        a->nextActor = NULL;

    E_ActorEvent* evt = new E_ActorEvent;
    evt->eventType = AEV_REMOVED;
    evt->actor = actor;
    G_NotifyActorEvent(evt); // > Notify the actor's removal.

    return true;

}

// > Perform damage checks on the actor pointed. If
//   the actor's health is smaller than 1 (it's not
//   a floating point number, so we can safely assume
//   that i < 1 is the same as i <= 0), we call the die
//   routine on it.
//
// > For the sake of modifiability, this function exists;
//   however, it is only an if statement with a call to
//   G_Die.
void G_DamageCheck(G_Actor* actor)
{
    if ( actor->damage.health < 1 )
        G_Die(actor);
}

// > Deal damage to an actor, and handle damage factors
//   (unless specified otherwise). Automatically calls
//   the damage check function (kills actor if health is
//   null or negative).
void G_TakeDamage(G_Actor* actor, char* damageType, int damage, bool checkFactors)
{   
    // > Apply damage factors.
    if ( checkFactors && actor->damageFactor_K != NULL && actor->damageFactor_V != NULL )
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 256 && actor->damageFactor_K[i] != ""; i++ )
            if ( std::strcmp(actor->damageFactor_K[i], damageType) == 0 )
                damage = damage * actor->damageFactor_V[i] / 1000;


    actor->damage.health -= damage;

    // > Damage shall be tracked by other _G_DamageTrack
    //   members as well!
    if ( damage < 0 )
        actor->damage.totalHeal -= damage;

    else
        actor->damage.totalDamage += damage;    

    if ( damage > 0 )
    {
        E_ActorEvent* evt1 = new E_ActorEvent;
        evt1->eventType = AEV_DAMAGE;
        evt1->eventData = damage;
        evt1->actor = actor;
        G_NotifyActorEvent(evt1); // > Notify the actor's damage.
    }

    else
    {
        E_ActorEvent* evt1 = new E_ActorEvent;
        evt1->eventType = AEV_HEAL;
        evt1->eventData = -damage;
        evt1->actor = actor;
        G_NotifyActorEvent(evt1); // > Notify the actor's heal.
    }

    E_ActorEvent* evt1 = new E_ActorEvent;
    evt1->eventType = AEV_MODHEALTH;
    evt1->eventData = -damage;
    evt1->actor = actor;
    G_NotifyActorEvent(evt1);   // > Notify any modification to the
                                //   actor's physical integrity.        

    G_DamageCheck(actor);
}
```

**actor.h**

```
#ifndef GUSTAVO_ACTORSYS_HEADER
#define GUSTAVO_ACTORSYS_HEADER

/*
 * Actor System (header)
 * (with Event System included)
 *
 * Author: Gustavo Ramos "Gustavo6046" Rehermann.
 * (c)2018. The MIT License.
 *
 * This system basically allows the creation of
 * Actors (entities), in a game world. This does
 * not handle 3D coordinates nor collision. I
 * have neither ideas nor time to implement those,
 * so I hope someone will implement those on top
 * of this code, either extending it or modifying it.
 *
 * For the sake of extensibility, actors aren't removed
 * when they die. That task is here delegated to the 
 * upper levels.
 *
 * For an example of a possible extension:
 *
 *      struct Vec3
 *      {
 *          int XYZ[3];
 *      }
 *
 *      struct G_PhysicalActor
 *      {
 *          G_Actor* baseActor;
 *          Vec3 pos;
 *          int colCylinderRadius;
 *          int colCylinderHeight;
 *          // ...
 *      }
 */

#define AEV_DEATH 0     // > Surprise! This actor died!
#define AEV_DAMAGE 1    // > This actor took positive damage.
#define AEV_HEAL 2      // > This actor took negative damage (heal).
#define AEV_MODHEALTH 3 // > This actor's health was modified (by
                        //   the G_TakeDamage function, most
                        //   likely).
#define AEV_CREATED 4   // > This actor was newly created.
#define AEV_REMOVED 5   // > This actor was removed from the master linked list..

// > This structure will track the physical integrity
//   of an actor. It is supported by standard functions,
//   like G_TakeDamage.
struct _G_DamageTrack
{
    int health;                 // > tracked actor's health

    unsigned int totalDamage;   // > tracked actor's total damage (scaled
                                //   by damage factors)
    unsigned int totalHeal;     // > tracked actor's total heal (negative damage)
};

struct G_Actor
{
    // char* name;              // > actor's human name
    // char* id;                // > actor's unique identifier
    unsigned int index;         // > actor's G_Actors index + 1.
                                //   If this is equal to 0, this actor
                                //   should be assumed not to be in 
                                //   G_Actors.

    _G_DamageTrack damage;      // > keeps track of 'health' (physical
                                //   integrity) and damage
    char* damageFactor_K[256];  // > this actor's damage factor map's keys
    int damageFactor_V[256];    // > this actor's damage factor map's values

    G_Actor* nextActor;         // > actors follow a linked list.
};

struct E_ActorEvent
{
    unsigned char   eventType;  // > event's type (as defined in AEV_* constants)
    int             eventData;  // > extra information about the event
    G_Actor*        actor;      // > pointer to event's reference actor

    E_ActorEvent*   nextEvent;  // > events, like actors, follow a linked list.
};

extern  E_ActorEvent*   E_BaseEvent;    // > Master actor event linked list.
extern  G_Actor*        G_Actors;       // > Master actor linked list.
extern  unsigned int    G_NumActors;

// > This function shall append actor events
//   to the master event linked list (I call
//   this event notification).
extern void G_NotifyActorEvent(E_ActorEvent* evt);

// > Returns the next actor event.
//   
extern E_ActorEvent* G_PollActorEvent();

// > Handle actor death (health being
//   smaller than or equal to 0).
extern void G_Die(G_Actor* actor);

// > Create an actor and append it to
//   the master Actor linked list.
extern G_Actor* G_CreateActor(int health);

// > Perform damage checks on the actor pointed. If
//   the actor's health is smaller than 1 (it's not
//   a floating point number, so we can safely assume
//   that i < 1 is the same as i <= 0), we call the die
//   routine on it.
extern void G_DamageCheck(G_Actor* actor);

// > Deal damage to an actor, and handle damage factors
//   (unless specified otherwise). Automatically calls
//   the damage check function (kills actor if health is
//   null or negative).
extern void G_TakeDamage(G_Actor* actor, char* damageType, int damage, bool checkFactors = true);

// > Removes this actor from the list, by address.
extern bool G_RemoveActor(G_Actor* actor);

#endif /* GUSTAVO_ACTORSYS_HEADER */
```

Below is a usage example/demo:

**actormain.cpp**

```
/*
 * Actor system usage example.
 *
 * Author: Gustavo Ramos "Gustavo6046" Rehermann.
 * (c)2018. The MIT License.
 */

#include <iostream>
#include "actor.h"

int main()
{
    G_Actor* myActor = G_CreateActor(80);
    G_Actor* myActor2 = G_CreateActor(200);

    myActor2->damageFactor_K[0] = "fire"; // Let's just say it's a dragon!
    myActor2->damageFactor_V[0] = 100;
    myActor2->damageFactor_K[1] = "default"; // And it has hard scales.
    myActor2->damageFactor_V[1] = 575;
    myActor2->damageFactor_K[2] = "water"; // But it hates water!
    myActor2->damageFactor_V[2] = 2420;

    std::cout << "Actor 0 address: " << myActor << "\n";
    std::cout << "Actor 1 address: " << myActor2 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Actor 0's initial health: " << myActor->damage.health << "\n";
    std::cout << "Actor 1's initial health: " << myActor2->damage.health << "\n";
    G_TakeDamage(myActor, "default", 30);
    G_TakeDamage(myActor, "default", 40);
    G_TakeDamage(myActor, "default", -30);
    G_TakeDamage(myActor, "default", 100);
    G_TakeDamage(myActor2, "fire", 314);
    G_TakeDamage(myActor2, "default", 120);
    G_TakeDamage(myActor2, "water", 90);
    std::cout << "Actor 0's final health: " << myActor->damage.health << "\n";
    std::cout << "Actor 1's final health: " << myActor2->damage.health << "\n";
    G_RemoveActor(myActor);
    std::cout << "Actor removed.\n";

    E_ActorEvent* evt;

    std::cout << "\n== EVENT LOG ==\n\n";

    // Print every damage/death event notified in the meanwhile.
    while ( evt = G_PollActorEvent() )
    {
        if ( evt->eventType == AEV_CREATED )
            std::cout << "Actor " << evt->actor->index << " was created!\n";

        if ( evt->eventType == AEV_DAMAGE )
            std::cout << "Actor " << evt->actor->index << " took " << evt->eventData << "hp damage!\n";

        else if ( evt->eventType == AEV_DEATH )
            std::cout << "Actor " << evt->actor->index << " has died!\n";

        else if ( evt->eventType == AEV_HEAL )
            std::cout << "Actor " << evt->actor->index << " healed " << evt->eventData << "hp!\n";

        else if ( evt->eventType == AEV_REMOVED )
            std::cout << "Actor " << evt->actor->index << " was removed from the actor list.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** This works when compiled with Open Watcom C++. Tell me if it doesn't work with your compiler!

Comment: Any reason for _not_ using `std::list`?

Comment: I don't even know why I made this in C++ instead of C, but I wanted to make a program/library that could be run under DOS.

Comment: I see quite a few uses of `new`. Still looking for the first `delete`...

Comment: @MikeBorkland my issue is that, if I don't use `new`, the Open Watcom compiler will simply allocate only one variable per function, not per function call, so `G_Actor newActor;` inside a function would not allocate a new actor, but instead allocate only one, and reuse it everytime the function is called. I don' t have much of a clue about deinitialization right now, but I'll try it.

Comment: I think this works: https://gist.github.com/Gustavo6046/2bead16a3c1e4da8f281affc6ded2d07

Answer (score 1):

Defining constants with #define is only ok in c. In C++ there are better alternatives. Consider using  instead `const int` or an `enum` for the states instead of `#define` in C++98.

If C++11 would be available you could even change the `#define`  to `constexpr`.

Is there a reason to use `unsigned int`? it is usually not worth using it. The extra precision you gain is  not worth it since it can lead to obscure bugs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587451/c-c-use-of-int-or-unsigned-int

`return 0` is not necessary to be added in the `main` function in c++. By definition it is auto generated by the compiler. This only applys for main.

Consider making a Actor class were you create the Actor take damage etc.